# Laravel 4 imagecache intervention not displaying images

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, image-caching, intervention

Here's the product page with an imagecached image: http://kmk-prof.kz/product/dx700lc

As you can see - image is not being displayed and has following url: /imagecache/catalogue/dx700lc-541a82fe99ac3.jpg

But when i try to browse that image just in my uploads folder - http://kmk-prof.kz/uploads/dx700lc-541a82fe99ac3.jpg it displays just fine.

Why could imagecache not work?

Here's the imagecache config.php:

```
'route' => 'imagecache',

'paths' => array(
    public_path('uploads'),
),

'templates' => array(
    'catalogue' => function($image) {
        return $image->fit(213, 213);
    },
),
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very hard to tell you why the image is not displaying without any code. 
Looking at the site, your image (in the html) is looking for a file in `/imagecache/catalogue/dx700lc-541a82fe99ac3.jpg` when your file is in  `uploads/dx700lc-541a82fe99ac3.jpg`.

you can do 2 things:

1. change the code to load the file from `uploads/dx700lc-541a82fe99ac3.jpg`.
2. or, change your image path to `/imagecache/catalogue/dx700lc-541a82fe99ac3.jpg`

if you want more help, please post your code.

PS. your **IMAGE URL** link doesn't work ^_^

Comment: Hello. If i change to your first method, then it would load directly from the uploads folder without any image manipulations (that's why i am using imagecache)

Obviously the 2nd method doesn't work, that's why i've created this question.

What for do you need the code? It's just Intervention/Imagecache package which creates the route: {imagecache}/{presetname}/{filename}